# How to install node-expat on Windows7

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, node-expat

I'm trying to install node expat on Windows 7 and i get the following error:

```
VCBUILD : error : project file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcproj' was not found or not a valid project file.
```

Any idea what i can do?